# If $x=1$, then its powers end with $1$

Tags: number-theory, algebra-precalculus

How to "show", that if $x=1$, then its powers will end with $1$?

Or, if $x=5$, how do we show it's powers end with $5$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am presuming you are talking about the last digit of a number in base $10$ being $1$ and $5$ implying the powers of that number will also end with $1$ and $5$.

I will give you a hint:

Give two numbers whose last digits are $1$, what does their product end with?

Comment: Give two numbers whose last digits are 1, what does their product end with? - 1

Comment: @lam: Right. So if $x^n$ ends with 1 and $x$ ends with 1, what does $x^{n+1}$ end with? What about $x^{n+2}$, $x^{n+3}$...?

Comment: One.Again.Am I right?

Comment: @lam: Right. Does that help you answer your question?

Comment: Two numbers (or more) whose last digits are 1, what does their product end with one.Thanks!But for the number four?

Comment: @lam: I didn't get you... What do you mean by number four?

Comment: For x=4.That's what I mean.

Comment: @lam: Umm...what about x=4? It does not end with either 5 or 1...

Comment: It's powers end with 6 or 4.

Comment: But how to show this?

Comment: @lam: I suggest you try out some powers yourself and try to work it out. The hints for the main question should be enough. This looks like homework to me.

Answer (score 12):

Use mathematical induction:

1. Show that $x^1$ ends in 1 (or 5).
2. Show that if $x^n$ ends in 1 (or 5), then $x^{n+1}$ also ends in 1 (or 5).  (Think about multiplying a number than ends in 1 by 1 (or ends in 5 by 5).)

Answer (score 6):

If you know modular arithmetic: $\rm\; e\equiv 1,5\;\Rightarrow\; e^2\equiv e \;\Rightarrow\; e^k\equiv e\pmod{10}\;$ for all $\rm\; k>0$

If not, use induction: suppose $\rm\;\; e^2 = e + 10j\;$ and  $\rm\; (e + 10 m)^k = e + 10n$

then $\rm\; (e + 10 m)^{k+1} = (e + 10n) (e + 10m) = e + 10(j+em+en+10mn)$

**REMARK** Note how the use of modular arithmetic has allowed us to rephrase the problem in a completely arithmetical form that makes the induction step utterly trivial - namely that $\rm 1^k \equiv 1$ or, more generally that $\rm\; e^2 \equiv e\;\Rightarrow e^k \equiv e\;$ for $\rm\: k>0$. This is but one very simple illustration of how one may often reduce problems about integers to simpler problems about integers modulo $\rm\:m\:$. Because the integers modulo $\rm\:m\:$ satisfy many of  the same arithmetical laws as the integers (associative, commutative, distributive, etc) - i.e. they form a ring - we can reuse our strong intuition about integers to help discover proofs in this simpler structure integers modulo $\rm\:m\:$. And, if we're lucky, we can sometimes lift these simple solutions from the integers modulo $\rm\:m\:$ up to the integers. If you study abstract algebra you'll see many more examples of problems solved by passing to such simpler structures (technically they are known as [quotient objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) - structures modulo a congruence, i.e. a structure-compatible equivalence relation). Said in an informal way, such **reduction to quotient objects** is a method to **divide and conquer** mathematically.

Comment: I don't think OP knows about modular arithmetic...

Comment: That's why I gave an alternative proof by induction, which requires no knowledge of modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that addition and multiplication are well-defined modulo $n$, then just work (mod 10).
Let $x_0 \in$ {1,5} be the ones digit of $x$.  Then for any $k$

$x^k \equiv x_0^k \equiv x_0$ (mod 10).